# How to detect that a Paragraph.Range is inside a TOC in a C# Word AddIn

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

I'm making a *MS-Word* Addin with some features. One of them is to remove excessive blank lines (the current rule says that the Document can't have more than two sequential blank lines and that it can't have blank lines after the last line of text).

I've made a code to try to achieve this:

```
private void formatText() {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs paragraphs = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs;
    Boolean isPreviousLineEmpty = false;
    Boolean isLastLine = true;

    for (int i = paragraphs.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphs[i];

        if (paragraph.Range.Text.Trim().Equals("")) {
            if (isLastLine) {
                paragraph.Range.Delete();
                continue;
            }

            if (isPreviousLineEmpty) {
                paragraph.Range.Delete(); //This is the line where the error happens
            }   

            isPreviousLineEmpty = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (isLastLine) {
            paragraph.Range.Text = paragraph.Range.Text.TrimEnd();
            isLastLine = false;
        }

        isPreviousLineEmpty = false;
    }
}
```

It was working untill I've added a "Table of Contents" (TOC) to the document. Now I get an error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot edit Range.'**

The reason is: there is a white line on the TOC that my code is trying to remove, and it can't. I've searched the documentation/internet and tried everything I could think of to be able to prevent my code from running on TOC lines, but nothing worked.

**I need a way to know that I can skip that line, because I don't need to delete blank lines inside TOCs.**

For the moment, what I can do is wrap the specific line who executes the deletion with a Try/Catch block, but I don't think this is the best solution (for I may be letting other errors go unnoticed, this is just a silencer).

Does anyone know the correct approach to this case?

---

**UPDATE:**

Following [Freeflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10341452/freeflow) comment I replaced all my method code with this:

```
private void formatText() {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find find = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().Find;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs paragraphs = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs;
    Boolean operationResult = true;

    //Remove blank lines at the end of the document
    for (int i = paragraphs.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphs[i];

        if (paragraph.Range.Text.Trim().Equals("")) {
            paragraph.Range.Delete();
            continue;
        }

        paragraph.Range.Text = paragraph.Range.Text.TrimEnd();

        break;
    }

    //Remove blank lines between paragraphs
    while (operationResult) {
        operationResult = find.Execute("^p^p^p", false, false, false, false, false, false, null, null, "^p^p",
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
    }
}
```

It has been working very well untill this moment. If any problem comes up, I'll post here.

Thanks for your comment. If you transform it in an answer I'll mark as the accepted one.

Comment: Why don't you just do a find and replace on ^p^p for ^p.

Comment: Maurice, ***PLEASE*** do not post an answer inside a question. Put in an an ANSWER box, then (in a couple of days) mark it as "the" answer. Note that Freeflow will not have seen your remark about writing up their comment as an answer.

Comment: And a comment about what you're trying to do, in general: This is a TOC. That means it's a **dynamically generated** field result. If the TOC is updated, any edits made will disappear. The only way to really fix this would be to figure out where these extra paragraph are coming from and remove those from the document.

Answer (score 3):

The Word object model has a useful method: `InRange`, which allows checking whether one range of text is part of another. Logically, then, it's possible to compare whether a paragraph's location is within a TOC.

Below is a test example, originally written in VBA. I'm converting it on-the-fly to C#, so there may be some minor syntax errors...

```
public void TestRangeInToc()
{
    Word.Document doc =Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
    bool HasToc = false;

    if(doc.TablesOfContents.Count > 0)
    {
        HasToc = true;
    }

    foreach(Word.Paragraph para In doc.Paragraphs)
    {
        if(HasToc)
        {
            if(IsRangeInTOC(para.Range, doc))
            {
               Debug.Print("in range");
               //skip this one
            }
        }
    }
}

public bool IsRangeInTOC(Word.Range rng, Word.Document doc)
{
    Word.TableOfContents toc         
    foreach(toc in doc.TablesOfContents)
    {
        if(rng.InRange(toc.Range))
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```